# Morris.js x Axis not arrange correctly

Tags: ajax, morris.js

**Good day**
Im having some trouble with my morris js chart.

[image]

instead of having 1-4 5-9 10-14 i receiving it at this kind of way. I already tried my query to ordered it asc but nothing happen.

Comment: It would be good to provide the query and the code manipulating your numbers you're using to be able to help you. I suspect you're ordering your numbers as string instead of integers, that's probably why 5-9 is at the end.

Answer (score 0):

You need to sort your dataset before providing it to your Morris chart.